# How to make an intrusive tree class in C# use generics?

Tags: c#, data-structures, intrusive-containers

In C# I have an *intrusive* tree structure that looks like this:

```
public abstract class Node
{
    Container parent;
    Node nextNode;
    Node previousNode;

    public abstract class Container : Node
    {
        Node firstChild;
        Node lastChild;
    }
}
```

The various objects that can be added to the tree inherit from either `Node` or `Container` depending on whether they can have children or not.

By making `Container` an inner class it means that it can access the private members in `Node` for managing the container's list of children.

This is all well and good. But now I wish to make it generic so that I can reuse it while maintaining type safety - basically moving all the tree functionality to a generic class above Node and another between Node and Container. Here's a rough design of what I'm trying to do:

```
public abstract class GenericNode<Node, Container>
    where Node : GenericNode<Node, Container>
    where Container : GenericNode<Node, Container>.GenericContainer
{
    Container parent;
    Node nextNode;
    Node previousNode;

    public abstract class GenericContainer : Node
    {
        Node firstChild;
        Node lastChild;
    }
}
```

Which, of course, doesn't work because you can't make `GenericContainer` inherit from `Node` (compiler error [CS0689](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f47cb6h7(v=VS.90).aspx)). Even if I drop the inner class requirement (say, by using `internal` and just being careful in my own library) I still can't figure out a design that doesn't run into the same problem (and error).

(I didn't think I would have to, but just to spell it out: **I am not trying to "fix" the compile error**, nor am I looking for a simple tree implementation. This is a container design question.)

And so now I'm a bit stumped. Does anyone have any better ideas about how to design this thing?

Edit: Be sure to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845966/how-to-make-an-intrusive-tree-class-in-c-use-generics/3846524#3846524), which is another stab at the design, that attempts to use extension methods to avoid the problem of "injecting" a class into the inheritance hierarchy (but unfortunately doesn't fully work).

Comment: Yes, the compilation error is because of your naming. Just name the type parameters TNode and TContainer, and it compiles just fine...

Comment: @Claus: No it isn't and no it doesn't (the reason your answer compiles is because you changed what GenericContainer inherits from).

Comment: Yes, of course. But I still wanted to point out the reason you got the CS0689 error was because you had conflicting names. So better if you left such issues out of a question ;)

Comment: Actually I was getting CS0689 because (as the error says) you `Cannot derive from 'Node' because it is a type parameter`. But deriving from a type parameter is (conceptually) *exactly what I want to do*. So then the design question becomes how to achieve a similar effect, without requiring this impossible (in C#) construct. I didn't get my type naming wrong - it was named like that deliberately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your extension method approach, what if you define the inheritance constraint (between Node and Container) on an interface instead, and decorate container classes with the interface.

```
{
    MyNode n = new MyNode();
    var c = new MyNode.MyContainer();
    c.AddChild(n);

    MySubNode s = new MySubNode();
    c.AddChild(s);

    OtherNode o = new OtherNode();
    o.AddChild(o);

    //compiler doesn't allow this, as you'd expect:
    //c.AddChild(o);
}        

public interface IContainer<TContainerType, TNodeType>
    where TNodeType : GenericNode<TContainerType, TNodeType>
    where TContainerType : TNodeType, IContainer<TContainerType, TNodeType>
{
}

public static class ContainerExtensions
{
    public static void AddChild<TContainerType, TNodeType>(this IContainer<TContainerType, TNodeType> self, TNodeType node)
        where TNodeType : GenericNode<TContainerType, TNodeType>
        where TContainerType : TNodeType, IContainer<TContainerType, TNodeType>
    {
        GenericNode<TContainerType, TNodeType>.AddChild(self as TContainerType, node);
    }
}

public class GenericNode<TContainerType, TNodeType>
    where TNodeType : GenericNode<TContainerType, TNodeType>
    where TContainerType : GenericNode<TContainerType, TNodeType>
{
    TContainerType parent;
    TNodeType nextNode;
    TNodeType previousNode;

    // Only used by Container
    TNodeType firstChild;
    TNodeType secondChild;

    internal static void AddChild(TContainerType container, TNodeType node)
    {
        container.firstChild = node;
        node.parent = container;
    }
}

public class MyNode : GenericNode<MyContainer, MyNode>
{        
}

public class MyContainer : MyNode, IContainer<MyContainer, MyNode>
{
}

public class MySubNode : MyNode
{
}

public class OtherNode : GenericNode<OtherNode, OtherNode>, IContainer<OtherNode, OtherNode>
{
}
```

Comment: This results in Containers no longer being Nodes.

Comment: (Regarding your updated answer @ revision 3.) I'm afraid that I originally left out the public and protected properties and methods that access those members for brevity. You can see the problem that lead me to the idea of using generics in your answer. That is - if you look at `AddChild`, the "fake" implementation of one such method - it is possible to add an `OtherNode` to a `MyContainer`, for example.

Comment: +1 and accepted (@ revision 5). It's not completely satisfying - because (by using `as`) you're doing a type check at runtime instead of compile time. But I think this may be as good as can be extracted from C#. Bravo for sticking with it.

Comment: the typecast also bothered me at first, but due to the constraints, there seems no way it will ever fail.
Therefore, I used "as" in stead of a hard cast.

Comment: Well - it can fail - but the end user has to be wilfully silly (by creating a class that implements the container interface but isn't the TContainerType). So I say that's good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution looks like:

```
public class Tree<T> : ITree<T> where T : INode{
    public T RootNode { get; private set; }
    public Tree(T rootNode){
        RootNode = rootNode;
    }
}

public interface ITree<T> where T : INode{
    T RootNode { get; }
}

public interface INode{
    INode Parent { get; }
    List<INode> Children { get; }
}

internal class Node : INode{
    public INode Parent { get; private set; }
    public List<INode> Children { get; private set; }
    public Node( INode parent, List<INode> children = new List<INode>()){
        Parent = parent;
        Children = children;
    }
}
```

HTH.

NOTE: Additional validations like ParentNode != null for child nodes; node belongs to the same parent to which it is being added etc. not implemented in this sample.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't really help. It doesn't solve the problem of differentiating between types that can have children, and types that cannot. (Also by using a `List`, it's not fully intrusive.)

Answer (score 0):

(Don't do this - leaving it in to help prevent anyone else from dropping the extension by accident too ;) )

Does this help?

```
public abstract class GenericNode<Node, Container>
    where Node : GenericNode<Node, Container>
    where Container : GenericNode<Node, Container>.GenericContainer<Node>
{
    Container parent;
    Node nextNode;
    Node previousNode;

    public abstract class GenericContainer<Branch> where Branch: GenericNode<Node, Container> 
    {
        private Leaf firstChild;
        private Leaf secondChild;
    }
}
```

Also compiles in 3.5. `Branch` is restricted to being a `Node` by the `GenericNode` declaration.

Comment: Uhmn... in this case GenericContainer is not a GenericNode - so it's not a tree any more ;)

Comment: Container cannot extend Node, because you have specified that it must extend GenericContainer (which, as I mentioned, is not a GenericNode).

Comment: Ah, you're right. I see what you mean; I lost the extension. Doh. Lean van der Walt's solution is the closest I get when I put it back.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had a working solution, but it doesn't fully work:

```
public abstract class GenericNode<Node, Container>
    where Node : GenericNode<Node, Container>
    where Container : Node
{
    Container parent;
    Node nextNode;
    Node previousNode;

    // Only used by Container
    Node firstChild;
    Node secondChild;

    public static class ContainerHelpers
    {
        public static void AddChild(Container c, Node n)
        {
            c.firstChild = n; // not a real implementation ;)
            n.parent = c;
        }
    }
}

// EDIT: This does not work correctly! (see example below)
public static class GenericNodeExtensionMethods
{
    public static void AddChild<Node, Container>(this Container c, Node n)
        where Node : GenericNode<Node, Container>
        where Container : Node
    {
        GenericNode<Node, Container>.ContainerHelpers.AddChild(c, n);
    }
}

//
// Example Usage
//

public class MyNode : GenericNode<MyNode, MyContainer>
{
}

public class MyContainer : MyNode
{
}

public class MySubNode : MyNode
{
}

public class OtherNode : GenericNode<OtherNode, OtherNode>
{
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyNode n = new MyNode();
        MyContainer c = new MyContainer();
        c.AddChild(n);

        MySubNode s = new MySubNode();
        //
        // This does not work because it tries to fill the generic in the
        // extension method with <MySubNode, MyContainer>, which does not
        // fulfil the constraint "where Container : Node".
        //
        //c.AddChild(s);

        OtherNode o = new OtherNode();
        o.AddChild(o);
    }
}
```

While the extension method method of exposing methods only for Container does not work correctly, structuring the GenericNode class like this has the nice property that Container and Node can be the same class - giving the end-user the option of having a specific type in the tree that can have children, or allowing all types to have children.

(Also for some reason the extension method doesn't show up in IntelliSense in VC# 2008 SP1, although it does in 2010.)

Still looking for a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to insulate the client from the actual structure of the tree entirely, by not exposing Node objects directly:

```
public interface ITagged<T>
{
    T Tag { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Tree<T>
{
    //All Tree operations are performed here (add nodes, remove nodes, possibly move nodes, etc.)
    //Nodes are only exposed as 'ITagged<T>', such as:
    public ITagged<T> Root { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<ITagged<T>> GetChildren(ITagged<T> item)
    {
        //Cast to Container and enumerate...
    }

    //Several other tree operations...

    private class Node : ITagged<T>
    {
        Container parent;
        Node nextNode;
        Node previousNode;

        public T Tag { get; set; }
    }

    private class Container : Node
    {
        Node firstChild;
        Node lastChild;
    }
}
```

The tree can now contain any type of data object, without having to descend from a special type or include any properties controlling tree structure.  The tree structure is all handled internally by the Tree class and all Tree operations are provided by the Tree class.  Now the client is completely insulated from implementation details.  All the client ever sees are their data objects.  If you still want to be able to still provide navigation from the nodes, you could provide a link back to the Tree in the node interface and then provide extension methods that use the Tree methods to implement the navigation.

Comment: What you have described seems to be a regular tree, not an intrusive tree.

Comment: @Andrew, You could use this type of pattern to implement any kind of tree; it's merely a way of tracking the generic content while insulating the implementation details of the tree.  You can easily remove the Root.  The other change I made was moving Container out of Node, since you would no longer need to have logic inside Node, but you could still keep them nested if you wanted.

Comment: The point of an intrusive tree is that the links between nodes are stored in the nodes themselves (the structure of the tree is "intrusive" into the nodes). This removes the need to store the tree structure externally to the actual data. One important effect of this is that manipulating the tree will never cause an allocation.

Comment: @Andrew, ah, okay, I see.  The design above allows manipulation without allocation, but does still require two objects (the node and the data it contains) and so an allocation when the node is first added.

Answer (score 0):

Just fix your generic-type parameter names, and remember to add the generic-type parameter to the inherited GenericNode.

ie.

```
public abstract class GenericNode<TNode, TContainer>
    where TNode : GenericNode<TNode, TContainer>
    where TContainer : GenericNode<TNode, TContainer>.GenericContainer
{
    public TContainer Parent { get; set; }
    public TNode Next { get; set; }
    public TNode Previous { get; set; }

    public abstract class GenericContainer : GenericNode<TNode, TContainer>
    {
        public TNode FirstChild { get; set; }
        public TNode LastChild { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Compiles just fine.

Comment: Yes it compiles fine. But it does not meet the design goals. Also sticking "T" in front of the type names doesn't actually do anything - they're just names. Your answer is almost identical to Leon van der Walt's first attempt: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2f1874c4-5a26-4607-9f2c-7a7eccbb7d70/view-source